# ¿Como revertir un conflicto después de haber ejecutado git pull?

Tags: git

Estaba trabajando localmente y en el remoto hicieron cambios y tuve que ejecutar git pull antes de subir mis cambios.

Hice commit a mis cambios antes de intentar ejecutar git pull.

Tengo un problema, al hacer pull surgio un conflicto, y quisiera revertir la situacion y devolver el repositorio al estado en el que estaba antes de ejecutar git pull.

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in assets/css/pages/project.js
```

Quisiera saber como podría hacer eso.

Gracias.

El commit que hice localmente sale registrado al ejecutar git log

Answer (score 2):

Si estás en medio de un merge (que es lo que hace pull por defecto), debes poder regresar todo a como estaba con ejecutar

```
git merge --abort
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenemos 2 opciones:

1. La primera como menciono @eftshif0, si estamos en el medio de un merge realizar un merge abort, con el comando:

   git merge --abort
2. La Segunda, si por lo contrario ya terminamos el proceso de merge y confirmamos, cambios que no eran correspondientes para esa branch la mejor opcion, es regresar a un commit previo, con el comando:

   git checkout  .

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).